# applications of the sphere theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I am looking for interesting applications of the [1/4-pinched sphere theorem](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_theorem). The theorem says: A compact, simply connected riemannian manifold whose sectional curvature K satisfies $1/4 < K \leq$ 1 (possibly after multiplying the metric by a constant) is homeomorphic (recently extended to "diffeomorphic") to the sphere. I just wanted to know: is it just a beautiful theorem or can you use it in concrete situations to derive some conclusions difficult to see otherwise? I am interested in this just because I am curious, I do not have any specific purpose in mind.

Comment: Well, it is a beautiful and natural theorem... Pleasure should be counted as an application!

Comment: One the top of this web page, there is a link labeled "how to ask".  Please read the page that is linked there, and revise your question.

Comment: When you have finished, please flag for moderator attention, so the question can be reopened.

Comment: I completely do get the aesthetic appeal of the theorem. I only wanted to see some applications of the theorem, that is, situations where you can infer something from the sphere theorem that is difficult to see otherwise.......

Comment: Mr Moderator, I don't know whether the question above is a mathoverflow question, it is certainly a math question. And I think I can cite quite a few questions that were asked in mathoverflow that were even broader/more vague than this....

Comment: I personally think that this is not such a bad question that it needed to be insta-closed.  I'd be interested in hearing answers!

Comment: I think I agree with Andy.  The question could perhaps be better formulated, but in asking for applications of a particular theorem it is less broad than many similar questions which are on the border of being appropriate.  If a few other people vote to reopen, I'll jump on that bandwagon...

Comment: plz guys, please feel free to suggest reformulations that would make the question better/precise....I am really interested in getting a few answers..


Comment: @whatever: Maybe you could state the Theorem (or at least link to the wiki page, if it exists) and speculate as to areas where you think it may find application.

Comment: meta thread: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1004/applications-of-the-sphere-theorem/ . @whatever: please read my comments on the meta thread. I've tried to carefully explain why I find this question very frustrating and what I think you can do to fix it.

Comment: @ anton
1.I have tried to explain the theorem
2.Why I care about it: I do not have any specific purpose in mind...just curious, that's all. There has been a lot of research around this theorem....that really makes you wonder.
3.This is a wiki page
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_theorem


Comment: @Mark 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_theorem


Comment: For me this is a theorem which works as an example to show different techniques in Riemannian geometry. [1/4-pinched sphere theorem is in my field of interests and I do not know any real applications; I will be very surprised if there are some.]

Comment: @Pete Clark, or whoever made the last edit, the Brendle-Schoen sphere theorem says that the manifold is DIFFEOMORPHIC (not merely homeomorphic) to a sphere under the assumption of strict pointwise quarter pinching. As for applications, I agree with Anton.

Comment: Not sure if this is what @whatever is looking for, but in the last chapter of this http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2011-48-01/S0273-0979-2010-01312-4/S0273-0979-2010-01312-4.pdf overview of the differentiable sphere theorem discusses how the method of proof can be used in other related problems, like what @Anton said.

Comment: @whatever, read Comparison Theorems in Riemannian Geometry, by Jeff Cheeger and David Ebin, undergraduate/beginning graduate level. There are more recent books with similar material as well. This will satisfy any curiosity you might have about the place of the two Sphere Theorems, homeomorphic and diffeomorphic,  as to difficulty and place in mathematics. Chapter 7 discusses alternate differentiable structures. Note that Calabi and Gromoll proved the Differentiable version in 1966, but needed a pinchng constant depending on dimension.. Finally, actually read Brendle and Schoen.  

Comment: @Igor: surely you have enough rep to edit it yourself to fix that! But in any case, since the OP is the one who included the line about homeomorphic and not diffeomorphic, perchance he is not interested in the Brendle-Schoen result? @whatever: note that since Brendle and Schoen's result is still fairly new (only 4 years old) and exciting, that is what most people would think of right now when you say quarter-pinching... do you care to clarify?

Comment: @Willie, I think people talk about Brendle-Schoen because it is a stronger (and also definitive) theorem. It would be interesting to find a Ricci flow free proof of the sphere theorem. For a survey of what can be done without Ricci flow see http://library.msri.org/books/Book30/files/abresch.pdf. 

Comment: @Willie I am a student and not a researcher....I was simply not aware of this. The do Carmo book I was using is probably older than this, so it cautions the reader that the result is NOT diffeomorphic and even hints at possible obstructions at proving diffeomorphism, Milnor's exotic spheres being one them...

Comment: @Igor: I know that the hypotheses imply that the manifold is diffeomorphic to a sphere (I learned that from the wikipedia article I inserted the link to).  But since the OP was referring to a particular theorem, I figured it was up to him to decide whether he meant the older theorem giving homeomorphism in the conclusion, or the rather recent (spectacular) theorem giving diffeomorphism.  

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The main theme of global Riemannian geometry is to derive topological conclusions from geometric assumptions. Sphere theorems provide various assumptions under which a manifold is (homeomorphic, diffeomorphic, or almost isometric) to a sphere.

The significance of sphere theorems is not in their applications or implications but in the beautiful mathematics they generated. Tools developed to prove various sphere theorems is a backbone of modern comparison geometry, and a great place to learn about it is [the survey](http://library.msri.org/books/Book30/files/abresch.pdf) by Abresch and Meyer.

More recently Brendle-Schoen used Ricci flow to prove a definitive [differentible sphere theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_theorem); this and closely related [work](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2008/167-3/p10) by Bohm-Wilking are (in my view) the most spectacular applications of Ricci flow beyond dimension three.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, those were really very helpful. I am particularly reading the survey by Abresch and Meyer now. I saw someone comment on the meta thread about the application of the sphere theorem to the aphericity of knot complements....can anyone tell me a reference for this?

Comment: @whatever: I doubt asphericity of knowt complements is related to this sphere theorem. It might be related to another one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_theorem_%283-manifolds%29

Answer (score 5):

An application occurs in the study of asymptotic behavior of complete manifolds with certain curvature decay.

Let M be a n-dimensional complete non-compact manifold.
Suppose that

1. M is simply-connected at infinity,
2. the sectional curvatures of M go to zero at infinity,
3. there exists a foliation of (n-1)-dimensional sub-manifolds on the ends of M
4. these sub-manifolds have controlled second fundamental form,

then you may use Gauss equation and the differential sphere theorem to say that these sub-manifolds are diffeomorphic to the sphere.